# How much meat is in one wild coconut?

Tags: coconut

I'm asking in reference to [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/54365/885) which I’m workin on in Worldbuilding.

I can look up the nutritional information on coconut and that gives vales for 100 gram portions.  But how many grams of that stuff is in one (wild!) coconut, on average?

Suppose you needed 1000 g of fresh shreaded coconut for a recipe. How many drupes would you buy?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how big wild coconuts typically are, but [the USDA says that one medium coconut has 397 grams of meat](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3656?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=35&offset=&sort=&qlookup=12104). Good enough for back-of-the-envelope calculations, perhaps?